# Using Jumbotron, CSS, and Wordpress to display background

Tags: html, css, wordpress, twitter-bootstrap

I'm trying to create my first Wordpress theme, and I've been stuck on this for a few hours. I know how to add images using HTML(Through Wordpress), but I can't add images in the CSS, specifically, through background-image.

My guess is that it has something to do with the file path, but I was sure I had everything right. Also, I tried checking for spelling errors. If I didn't mess up the file path, I don't know what I did.

Does anyone have any ideas of what is wrong?

```
.jumbotron {
  background-image: url('Images/header.jpg')
  height: 500px;
  background-repeat: no-repeat;
  background-size: cover;
}
```

To give additional information about the file path, All the files are inside of the theme's folder. The CSS stylesheet, header.php, footer.php, and the "Images" folder are located here. In the images folder is a picture named header.jpg.

Comment: 1) remove the apostrophes around the url 2) the file image has to be relative to the style sheet

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Fix this:

```
background-image: url('Images/header.jpg')
```

to

```
background-image: url('Images/header.jpg');
```

and maybe try adding `no-repeat` like:

```
background-image: url('Images/header.jpg') no-repeat;
```

Comment: Yeah, I can't believe I forgot the semicolon. That worked, thanks so much!

Answer (score 1):

the problem is that you forgot `;` after `url()`